# How to Prevent Users From Viewing Other Users Data (in Custom Objects)

Tags: force.com

I am trying to configure our SalesForce users so they will not be able to view records (of custom objects) which were not created by them.

Can you please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand this is a straightforward question: set the sharing settings to Private on those objects. to do this go to Security > Sharing Settings to edit the organization-wide default sharing settings of any such objects to "Private".

On the other hand record-level security and sharing is a huge topic with a lot of things to learn about.

I suggest digging into the docs and reading about this to learn. You can start in this article [here on the Salesforce Developers web site.](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Overview_of_Force.com_Security#Record-based_Sharing) This link has an anchor to the section on record security.

But also look into the online help and training. As there is a lot there for learning on how to set this up.

Comment: **Your job is not done** there is so much more to learn. Giving access back to the users you want has number of steps you'll want to do, the last of which is write code. Please research and learn this platform feature or you will wind up solving problems in code that you might not need to.